# Is it possible to use just `npm start` to run angular, flask and mongodb

Tags: angular, mongodb, flask, npm

My team creating an webservice that using Angular as a view, Flask for the server and MongoDB for the Database.

But once when we want to start our webservice, it should run 3 things :

`npm start` (running the angular)
`python3 run.py` (running the flask server api)
`sudo service mongod start` (running the mongodb)

But I need the fastest way if there is any, so back to my question :

> Is it possible to use just `npm start` to run angular, flask and
>   mongodb ?

Additional information of my environment :

- Angular CLI: 8.2.1
- Node: 12.8.0
- OS: linux x64 (Ubuntu 18.0.4)
- npm : 6.10.2

Comment: Why not just write some powershell or an VS Extension to encapsulate this for you.

Comment: I don't know what it is, can you tell me more

Comment: I just wanted to know if there is any way to run that 3 together with npm start. If you know please tell me. If you don't know please don't ask anything that not really helping me.

Answer (score 4):

you can edit the package.json and add a new command.

```
'start-all': 'mongod start && python3 run.py && ng serve'
```

This way the developer can run `npm run start-all` to execute all the commands.

Comment: Thanks It works but just for the mongoDB and Angular or mongoDB and Flask (beacause MongoDB is a background app). While the flask and angular need to create a thread and listen to a specific port. So how can I run the angular serve after the flask ?